# Mongoengine query to get only filtered embedded documents

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have this models:

```
class Sub(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()

class Main(Document):
    subs = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Sub))
```

When i use this query, it returns all of `Main` data but i just need `subs` that their `name` is `'foo'`.

query: `Main.objects(__raw__={'subs': {'$elemMatch': {'name': 'foo'}}})`

For example with this data:

```
{
  subs: [
          {'name': 'one'}, 
          {'name': 'two'}, 
          {'name': 'foo'}, 
          {'name': 'bar'}, 
          {'name': 'foo'}
        ]
}
```

The result must be:

```
{
  subs: [
         {'name': 'foo'}, 
         {'name': 'foo'}
        ]
}
```

Note that in mongodb client, that query returns this values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: I want do that in mongoengine and python!

Comment: You will write the same query in mongoengine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to change your data model then try this:

```
class Main(Document):
    subs = ListField(StringField())

Main.objectsfilter(subs__ne="foo")
```

---

I propose this approach assuming that the embedded document only has one field in which case it is redundant.

Comment: No. My real embedded documet has more attributes. Here i just put one field for simplicify.

Comment: Try subs__name_ne="foo" ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine provides the [`.aggregate(*pipeline, **kwargs)`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=aggregate#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) method which performs a  aggregate function.

MongoDB 3.2 or newer

```
match = {"$match": {"subs.name": "foo"}}
project = {'$project': {'subs': {'$filter': {'as': 'sub',
                                   'cond': {'$eq': ['$$sub.name', 'foo']},
                                   'input': '$subs'}}}}

pipeline = [match, project]
Main.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
```

MongoDB version <= 3.0

```
{'$redact': {'$cond': [{'$or': [{'$eq': ['$name', 'foo']}, {'$not': '$name'}]},
                       '$$DESCEND',
                       '$$PRUNE']}}
pipeline = [match, redact]
Main.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
```